# java appending strings doesn't work

Tags: java, string, button, append

I have a java program that has so many buttons with a text on it , whenever a user press the button the text inside a button should be added in an empty string ,

example,

String store = "";

if a user press 'A' then then the letter 'A' stored in the String variable 'store' if then a user press 'B'

then store must be equals to 'AB' , but this is not happening in my case , what happening is the previous String is simply replaced by the new one :S,

Here is the code,

```
String Text = "";

   for ( int count = 0; count < names.length; count++ ){

       if (event.getSource()==buttons[count]){
           Text += buttons[count].getText();
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Text);
       }

   }
```

What am i doing wrong ? why the string is not adding new values ? why it replacing the previous ones ? :S

Comment: The code you've quoted should be appending (because of the `+=`). If you're seeing `Text` get overwritten, it must be elsewhere in the code.

Comment: `Text`  should be `text` using common Java nomenclature.  Please learn the conventions and use them consistently.  Especially for code that is 'open source' or might be worked on or looked at by other people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `Text` a local variable inside your action listener? In that case it will always be re-initialized. Make it a member of your class.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that you accidently clear the `Text` variable before you press the second button.